ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Missing dependencies for SOCKS support
When I tried to pip install pysocks this is what happened:
C:\Users\User> pip install pysocks
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.                 

(Original Screenshot)
How do I fix this?

Correct way with capital py -m pip install PySocks instead of pysocks

Python package name isn't case sensitive.

Downloading PySocks-1.7.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (13 kB)
Downloading PySocks-1.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Installing collected packages: PySocks
Successfully installed PySocks-1.7.1

Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem.
